# python access main program variable from outside

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and wondering why it can access the variable defined in main program from outside, but can't in a self-defined function.

```
def f():
    print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [1,2,3]
    f()         # output: [1,2,3]
```

but encounter error when do it in a function

```
def f1():
    l1 = [1,2,3]
    f2()

def f2():
    print(l1)    # error: global name 'l1' is not defined

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1()
```

The first example really confused me, AFAIK, it's an error in C/C++ or some other languages, because we can't reference a undefined variable. So why it's legal here and why the second example is not legal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `if` block is not scoping the variable, it's merely conditionally declaring it. If your program is running as `__main__` (i.e. is the primary script being executed), `l` will be declared as globally scoped variable, and hence is available when `f` is executed. It's the same as:

```
if True:
    l = []

def f1():
    print(l)
```

Which is the same as:

```
l = []

def f1():
    print(l)
```

It does not matter whether `l` is declared before or after the function, it only matters that it's declared by the time the function body is *executed*.

However, declaring the variable inside the function `f1` scopes it to `f1`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your code:

First, you define a function named `f1()`. and you define a variable named `l1` in `f1()`. And `f1` will call `f2()`:

```
def f1():
    l1 = [1,2,3]
    f2()
```

And then, here is another function named `f2()` , and this will print `l1`

```
def f2():
    print(l1)
```

Then, you'll call the `f1()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1()
```

---

**What's wrong?**

From `help(global)`:

> The "global" statement is a declaration which holds for the entire
>   current code block.  It means that the listed identifiers are to be
>   interpreted as globals.
>
> It would be impossible to assign to a global
>   variable without "global", although free variables may refer to
>   globals without being declared global.

As you can see, you should use `global` before you define `l1` . So try this:

```
def f1():
    global l1
    l1 = [1,2,3]
    f2()

def f2():
    print(l1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1()
```

**Demo:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

And you also can use `l1` as a argument like this:

```
def f1():
    global l1
    l1 = [1,2,3]
    f2(l1)

def f2(arg):
    print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1()
```

That's OK, and `arg` is a variable, you can use it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

`l` in the first example is defined globally and is therefore automatically in all functions (read-only, mind you), as soon as you do l=1 within function scope it will be a local variable unless you explicitly add a `global l` (which is bad practise usually).

Comment: "Read-only" is not exactly correct. You can *modify the value* if the value is mutable. E.g. `l.append(4)` will work just fine.